# Constructing expressions that produce integers by only using digits in string '2017' and high school level operators and functions

Tags: python, performance

At school, we have a competition where the winner is determined by the length of their unbroken sequence of expressions that evaluate to integers 0 to n. 
You must use the next year's number in the correct order, every digit exactly once.

example:

```
0 = 2*0*17   
1 = 2-01^7  
2 = 2-0*17  
...
```

The competition doesn't have a section for computer-aided results, but I thought I would try it for fun.

The problem is, I don't know how to do this efficiently.
In Python 3.5, I am using
`itertools.product('2017()*/+-',repetitions=a)`
where a is an integer 4 to n to gather different lengths of expressions,
and picking the results that evaluate to integers and fit the criteria.
This takes more than `O(10^n)` time.

Is there a way to do this more efficiently in Python? 
If I should change language, what would be relatively easy to write but efficient?

Here is my whole code:

```
import itertools
import timeit

max_length = 8
min_val = 0
max_val = 100

start_time = timeit.default_timer()

year = '2017'
special_chars = '()*/+-'
these_chars = year + special_chars


def perm(seq, n):
    for p in itertools.product(seq, repeat=n):
        yield p

# Does every character in str_a occur in str_b 
# in the right order and exactly once, with arbitrary in-betweens
def right_order(str_a, str_b):
    list_a = list(str_a)
    list_result = []
    for c in str_b:
        if c in str_a:
            list_result.append(c)
    if list_result == list_a:   
        return True
    else:
        return False

def strs(length, dictionary):
    for a in perm(these_chars, length):
        cand = 0
        a = ''.join(a)
        try:
            cand = eval(a)
            if int(cand) != cand:
                continue
        except:
            pass


        if right_order(year, a) == True: 
            if not any(c in '()' for c in str(cand)) and min_val <= cand <= max_val and '//' not in a: # To remove tuples and non-standard operators
                if cand in dictionary:
                    if len(dictionary[cand]) < 10:  
                        dictionary[cand].append(a)
                else:
                    dictionary[cand] = [a]
    return dictionary

result_dict = {}
for i in range(len(year),max_length + 1):
    result_dict = strs(i, result_dict)



for k,v in sorted(result_dict.items()):
    key = str(k) + ': '
    values = "   ".join(v[0:4])

    print('{:<8} {}'.format(key, values),end=' ')

    print('...' * (len(v) > 4))



print()
stop_time = timeit.default_timer()
print('execution time: ' + str(stop_time - start_time))



input('EXIT')
```

Comment: Can the special characters only exist in the three "spots" between the number in the year, or can special characters appear at the ends of the string (i.e. `-2*0+1^7` as passing for `1`? Also, casting a string to integer as you are doing is not the same as making a mathematical interpretation of the string. I think this basis for your approach is wrong. Why do you need to check for order of numbers in your approach? This is known up front, so should be enforced when building various permutations of the string.

Comment: What are the limits on the special characters? Can I use `2! + 0 * 17` for the digit 2?

Comment: @MikeBrant   I would think that the expression that you provided is accepted. There is no rule regarding it. The interpretation of the string is done here: `cand = eval(a)`. When writing this I thought that including special rules in the generating of the strings may slow it down because the backend library is optimised.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger   Factorials are accepted. All High school level functions and operators are accepted except for ceiling, floor and round. At least that is what I got from the rules.

Comment: So `-(2 << 01) + 7` is acceptable for 3? I'm sorry but "High school level operators" feels vague to me. Can you provide a (more or less) complete list of what is accepted?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger

Comment: @MathiasEttinger   It means mathematical operators. So no bitshift. Regular operators are accepted: * / + -    High school level functions, like trigonometric functions and factorials are also accepted. I don't have a whole list, because the rules don't include it.

Comment: Would implicit multiplication be allowed? So `-2(0^1/7)` for `-2*(0^1/7)` which evaluates to `0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where your code is currently lacking is using all the knowledge you have. You already know that in the end the digits have to be in order and that in between the digits there can (or can not) be an operator.

This means, we only need to generate all strings of the form `s = "{}2{}0{}1{}7{}"`, where the `{}` denote a place for an operator.

In addition, we know that certain operators will never make sense at the beginning (like `/`) and most will not make sense at the end either (basically, only `)` makes sense there).

If we use this fact, we can end up with something like:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import product
from math import *

allowed_begin = set(["", "+", "-", "sin(", "cos(", "tan(", "exp(", "("])
allowed = allowed_begin | set(
    ["*", "/", "**", "*sin(", "*cos(", "*tan(", "*exp(", "*(", ")"])
allowed_end = set(["", ")"])

def find_expressions():
    expressions = defaultdict(list)
    template = "{}2{}0{}1{}7{}"
    for ops in product(allowed_begin, allowed, allowed, allowed, allowed_end):
        try:
            expression = template.format(*ops)
            n = eval(expression)
            if n >= 0 and n % 1 == 0:
                print n, x
                expressions[n].append(expression)
        except Exception:
            pass

    return expressions

if __name__ == "__main__":
    expressions = find_expressions()
    print sorted(expressions.keys())
```

This runs in about 0.5s on my machine and finds expressions for
`0.0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20.0, 21, 26, 27, 28, 30, 34, 37, 120, 140, 160, 194, 208, 340, 1407, 2017, 32768, 1.1719142372802612e+16, 13107200000000000000000L, 6.327431707155585e+60, 1.7911398206275708e+84, 2.1540324218248465e+90, 4.572185553551339e+147`. They are stored in `expressions` and all possible expressions for an existing key can be accesses via e.g. `expressions[22]`.

Note that I chose to allow `*(` as an operator, meaning implicit multiplication (see comment on the question). If you think this is not allowed, just take them out of the allowed operators.

The loop approach has one advantage over `itertools.permutations`. It allows `a == b == c == d`. Whereas permutations does not:

```
>>> list(itertools.permutations([1,2], 2))
[(1,2), (2,1)]
```

Note the absence of `(1,1)` and `(2,2)`.

Comment: there is https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product that solves your nested for loops and makes it easy to read.

Comment: @Alex Thanks, I knew there was some `itertools` way, but did not have the time to look for it. Edited my answer using `itertools.product`.

Comment: you can add `factorial(` and `*factorial(` to your sets.

Comment: Also this is odd that you can't find anything for 11: `2+cos(0)+1+7`… Seems like you missed `+cos(` and `-cos(` as well.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Yes, that would be possible. (I actually have some code that tries also all combinations of two operators in every spot between the digits, where this is included. But that code runs for ages...).

Comment: @Graipher   Thank you very much! What is the purpose of checking if `__name__ == "__main__"` ?

Comment: It allows you to do in another script `from script1 import *` to get all objects in this code (if it is called `script1.py`), but without executing the code guarded by this `if` clause.

Comment: @Graipher   Interesting. Does defaultdict support default types for values, as you apparently used it? What about nested functions?

Comment: Yes, it supports only default types (not default values, which you can achieve with a normal dict and `dict.get(key, default_value)`). It does not support `defaultdict(defaultdict(list))` to create a nested defaultdict, unfortunately. But you can subclass it and harcode e.g. `list` to create a `defaultdict_list` and nest that in a `defaultdict`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the shortist, ugliest solution possible, this is only 3 lines

```
import itertools, re
from fractions import Fraction as f
print(re.sub(r'\((\d)\)',r'\1',[a for a in[[b.format(*c) for b in("f(8){0}f(3){1}f(8){2}f(3)","(f(8){0}f(3)){1}f(8){2}f(3)","(f(8){0}f(3){1}f(8)){2}f(3)","(f(8){0}(f(3){1}f(8))){2}f(3)","((f(8){0}f(3)){1}f(8)){2}f(3)","f(8){0}(f(3){1}(f(8){2}f(3)))","f(8){0}((f(3){1}f(8)){2}f(3))","(f(8){0}f(3)){1}(f(8){2}f(3))") if eval(b.format(*c))==24]for c in itertools.product('+-/*', repeat=3)]if a][0][0].replace('f','')))
```

The basic idea is that you evaluate strings that you fill in with regex substitutions.

Comment: Short code is not required, and this is not a general solution.

Comment: I know, I just happened to have this lying around from a previous attempt at a similar problem. I am not saying that it is the best or fastest solution.

Comment: @OscarSmith your answer offers an alternative to OP's code. Please provide some more context to your answer and explain why would you do it like this. Don't forget, this is not SO.